# what is alternative to ffmpeg for generating thumbnails

Tags: php, image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, thumbnails

Currently I am using `ffmpeg` to generate thumbnails from the uploaded video. Its working fine. But, i guess there should be better option to this.  So, i am looking for the alternative to generate thumbnail from ffmpeg.

Currently i am using PHP. So, any solution in php will be great. I was thinking about `imagemagick` but i am not sure about it.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions are welcome.

Hope this question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can grab the frame at 100% using ffmpeg and then downsize / edit it with either GD or ImageMagick

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But i do not want to use ffmpeg any more so looking for its alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never tried it befoe, but I think MEncoder is generally regarded as the alternative to FFMPEG. Niggles' statement about resizing is probably your best for resizing the thumbnails